# Getting data to display on my site from database in Codeignator 3

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Hello i am stuck with how can i get data from database to display it on my webpage, where i can delet and edit users. So i want to put that data in Admin_Podatki. i would like some help so i can finish my final project

VIEWS:
views/Auth/Admin_Podatki

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="author" content="boris">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Avtohiša Carbon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url();?>assets/style2.css">
    <title>Avtohiša Carbon</title>
 </head>

 <body>
    <header class="header">
        <section class="flex">

        <div class="logo">
            <a href="Admin_Domov"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/slike/logo.png'); ?>"  width="237px" height="100px"/></a>
        </div>

            <nav class="Navbar">
                <a href ="<?php echo site_url();?>Auth/Admin_Domov">Domov |</a>
                <a href ="<?php echo site_url();?>Auth/Admin_Servis">Servis |</a>
                <a href ="<?php echo site_url();?>Auth/Admin_PVozil">Prodaja vozil |</a>
                <a href ="<?php echo site_url();?>Auth/Admin_ONas">O nas |</a>
                <a href ="<?php echo site_url();?>Auth/Admin_Kontakti">Kontakt |</a>
                <a href ="<?php echo site_url();?>Auth/login_form">Odjava |</a>
                <a href ="<?php echo site_url();?>Auth/Admin_Podatki">Podatki</a>
            </nav>
    </section>
    </header>   
    <div class="container domov">

    
<h1 class="heading" data-aos="zoom-out">Podatki O uporabnikih </h1>
<section>
   <div class="details">
      <div class="box" data-aos="zoom-in">
         <h3>Podatki</h3>
         <?php  echo $this->session->userdata('name');?>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>

<div class="credit">
         Copyright &copy; 2023 &mdash; Zaključna Naloga boris
      </div>

 <script><?php require_once("assets/Java/Nav.js");?></script>
</body>

</html>
```

MODELS:
auth_model

```
<?php

class auth_model extends CI_Model{


    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library("session");
        $this->load->helper('url');
        error_reporting(0);
    }

    public function register_user(){

        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $con_password=$this->input->post('con_password');
       

        if($password!=$con_password){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('worng','Potrjeno geslo ni enako geslu, ki ste ga vpisali!');
            redirect('Auth/register');
        }else{
            $data=array(
                "name"=>$this->input->post('name'),
                "email"=>$this->input->post('email'),
                "gender"=>$this->input->post('gender'),
                "password"=>$password
            );

            $this->db->insert('users',$data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('suc','Uspešno ste bili registrirani, prosim prijavite se.');
            redirect('Auth/');
        }
    }
    

    public function login_user(){

        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $gender=$this->input->post('gender');
       
       
        
        $this->db->where('email',$email);
        $this->db->where('password',$password);
        $query=$this->db->get('users');
        $find_user=$query->num_rows($query);
       
        
        if($email == 'admin@gmail.com'){

            $this->session->set_userdata('name', $query->row()->name);
            $this->session->set_userdata('email', $query->row()->email);
            $this->session->set_userdata('gender', $query->row()->gender);
            $this->session->set_userdata('log','logged');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('suc','Uspešno ste se prijavili');
            redirect('Auth/Admin_Domov');
            }

        elseif($find_user>0){
            
            $this->session->set_userdata('name', $query->row()->name);
            $this->session->set_userdata('email', $query->row()->email);
            $this->session->set_userdata('gender', $query->row()->gender);
            $this->session->set_userdata('log','logged');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('suc','Uspešno ste se prijavili');
            redirect('Auth/Domov');
            }
    
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('warning','Narobe podatki!!!');
            redirect('Auth/');
        }
    
    }

    public function SRV(){  

        $Date=$this->input->post('Date');
        $Time=$this->input->post('Time');
        $Servis=$this->input->post('Servis');
        $query=$this->db->get('users');
        $find_user=$query->num_rows($query);

        if($find_user>0){

            $this->session->set_userdata('Date', $query->row()->Date);
            $this->session->set_userdata('Servis', $query->row()->Servis);
            $this->session->set_userdata('Time', $query->row()->Time);
        }
    }

    public function MP(){  

        $Date=$this->input->post('Date');
        $Time=$this->input->post('Time');
        $Servis=$this->input->post('Servis');
        $query=$this->db->get('users');
        $find_user=$query->num_rows($query);

        if($find_user>0){

            $this->session->set_userdata('Date', $query->row()->Date);
            $this->session->set_userdata('Servis', $query->row()->Servis);
            $this->session->set_userdata('Time', $query->row()->Time);
        }
    }

    public function PKL(){  

        $Date=$this->input->post('Date');
        $Time=$this->input->post('Time');
        $Servis=$this->input->post('Servis');
        $query=$this->db->get('users');
        $find_user=$query->num_rows($query);

        if($find_user>0){

            $this->session->set_userdata('Date', $query->row()->Date);
            $this->session->set_userdata('Servis', $query->row()->Servis);
            $this->session->set_userdata('Time', $query->row()->Time);
        }
    }


    function Admin_Podatki(){
        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $email=$this->input->post('email');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $gender=$this->input->post('gender');
        $Date=$this->input->post('Date');
        $Time=$this->input->post('Time');
        $Servis=$this->input->post('Servis');

        $query=$this->db->get('users');

    }

}
?>
```

CONTROLlERS:
Auth

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/login');
    }

    public function register(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/register');
    }

    public function registration_form(){
        $this->auth_model->register_user();
    }

    public function login_form(){
        $this->auth_model->login_user();
        
    }

    /*Uporabnik*/
    public function Domov(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Glavna');
    }

    public function Servis(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Servis');
    }

    public function PVozil(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/PVozil');
    }

    public function ONas(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/ONas');
    }

    public function Kontakti(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Kontakti');
    }

    public function SRV(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/SRV');
    }

    public function MP(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/MP');
    }

    public function PKL(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/PKL');
    }


    /*Admin*/ 

    public function Admin_Domov(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_Glavna');
    }

    public function Admin_Servis(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_Servis');
    }

    public function Admin_PVozil(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_PVozil');
    }

    public function Admin_ONas(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_ONas');
    }

    public function Admin_Kontakti(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_Kontakti');
    }

    public function Admin_Podatki(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_Podatki');
    }

    public function Admin_SRV(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_SRV');
    }

    public function Admin_MP(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_MP');
    }

    public function Admin_PKL(){
        $this->load->view('Auth/Admin_PKL');
    }

}

?>
```

DATABASE
[This my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBXj0.png)

i tryed to get it working

Comment: You appear to have stored PlainText Passwords!! PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Or I am sure Codeigniter has a way of doing that built in